# Asp.Net MVC 5 with Google Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a Asp.Net MVC 5 Website. I commented in the google authentication. So I can register myself with an Google Login.

In my application, we have to get the calendars of the users.
So I added in the Startup.Auth.cs-File

```
        var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"],
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google"),
        };
        googleOptions.Scope.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar);
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
```

Now the user gets asked if he want to share his calendar with us. Allright.

But how can I save in Asp.Net MVC 5 the google user in the database and also get his google calendar.
I tried many things like

```
var calendarConnection = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer());
var calendars = calendarConnection.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items;
```

But these things doesnt really help.

I hope you understand my problem and can help me.

Comment: Instead of using the entire calendar list, parse the JSON response(what ever information you want to store in the data base) then store the information in the data base.

Comment: @SGC Thanks for your replay. The problem, is that the first code snippet is in the Startup.OAuth Class. The sdecond is in my own controller. So I dont know, how I have to authorize myself on google in this controller, that i can get the calendar data from the currently logged in user. Can anyone post a little Code snippit how it works and how i can put the data in the database?

Thanks